# Errno::ECONNRESET while sending email using Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Until recently my email functionality worked perfectly fine. But now throws the error Errno::ECONNRESET Connection reset by peer:

Here is how my application.rb looks like :

```
Module xyz
Class Application < Rails::Application
config.action_mailer.delivery_methos=:smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings= {
:address => 'mail.xyz.com',  #smtp address
:port => 587,
:domain=> 'www.xyz.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true

}
```

Earlier, I used the direct smtp server address, it worked for a while and I got this same error. So, I started using the corresponding IP address for the smtp address that I got using the command nslookup, it worked fine with out any problem for a long time until now.

Now it does not work either way (IP Address or SMTP address). Am I missing something here.

Thanks !

**EDIT :** 
SMTP Server works perfectly fine and sends out email using the BLAT tool.

Comment: If you've not changed your code and it suddenly stopped working, the server is probably at fault.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @WesFoster . I dont think so as the mails were sent out perfectly fine using the a different tool called 'Blat' with the same server address

Comment: That's good information to include in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the configuration settings has done the trick :
Changed the port to 25 and starttls to false and added openssl setting and set it to 'none'.

```
Module xyz
Class Application < Rails::Application
config.action_mailer.delivery_methos=:smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings= {
:address => 'mail.xyz.com',  #smtp address
:port => 25,
:domain=> 'www.xyz.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => false,
:openssl_verify_mode => 'none'

}
```